# Does struct.pack and encode Produce The Same Byte-String? Python

Tags: python, struct, byte, encode, binary-data

I got quite confused about the difference between `struct.pack()` and `encode`. To my understanding, the output of both `struct.pack()` and `encode` is byte-string. And that `struct.pack()` is used to convert numbers into bytes, while `encode` is used to convert string into bytes. Is my understanding right?

Then what if when you `struct.pack('format',something)` and `something.encode('utf-8')` which return the same byte-string. Then how do you tell if the byte-string represents a number or a string?
eg:

```
bstring = b'\xc3\xa9'
a = bstring.decode('utf-8')
b = struct.unpack('>H',bstring)
print(a,b)

>>>é (50089,)   #see, using different converting methods return different results
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were given an object of class 'bytes', such as `b'\xc3\xa9'`, you wouldn't know what it represented, whether that be a number or a string or something else, without any additional information.

You could decode it using utf-8

```
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-8')
'é'
```

You could also decode it using utf-16 and get a different result

```
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode('utf-16')
'꧃'
```

`encode` is a string method. So, yes, it operates on a string object only and its purpose is to translate a string, using the prescribed encoding scheme (e.g. utf-8), into a bytes object and return it.

`struct.pack()` is NOT just meant to convert numbers into a bytes object. It converts an arbitrary number of python values (integer, bool, float, and/or even bytes) into a bytes object that corresponds exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. You can think of a C struct as analogous to a Python Tuple or NamedTuple. Indeed, `struct.unpack()` returns a Python Tuple.

struct could be used to load binary data, stored in files or from network connections, written using the C language -- or written using Python `struct.pack()` or some other language's equivalent version of `struct.pack()` -- into analogous Python values.